Class deriving from virtual pure, auto generation of override from a template
I'm using the Subject/Observer pattern in a way that I have a class observing 2 kinds of event:
class manager : public observer<eventA>, observer<eventB>

To be valid, the manager class must implement an Update function for each event type, but what could I do if those functions can basically be written by a template?
So, instead of:
class manager : public observer<eventA>, observer<eventB> {
void Update(const eventA& ) { /* do something */ }
void Update(const eventB& ) { /* do something */ }
}

I may be error prone to use a template like:
template<typename T> void Update(const T&) { /* do something */} 

I implemented something based on:

a template function named update_internal
and a macro to generate the various 'real' implementations for all the types.

It works (similar to the pseudo-code below), but I'm looking for a more elegant solution! Any idea?
class manager : public observer<eventA>, observer<eventB> {
template<typename T> void Update_Internal(const T&) { /* do something */} 

#define GEN(TYPE) void Update(TYPE a) { Update_Internal(a); }

GEN(eventA);
GEN(eventB);
}


A template function cannot override a virtual function, period, whatever you do you will need to declare two functions in there.

You can create a CRTP class observer_crtp<event, Derived> that overrides the handler to invoke your function, then inherit that instead of observer, but IMO declaring two methods is fine.

Side note, using inheritance to implement the observer pattern is a bit outdated. In C++ you can do things with std::function's to register callbacks.  And even better you can do it without using macros (which are best avoided too)

With CRTP, you might do
template <typename Derived, typename Event>
class observer_crtp : public observer<Event>
{
public:
    void Update(const Event& event) override { static_cast<Derived*>(this)->UpdateT(event); }
};

// Factorize the using
template <typename Derived, typename... Events>
class observers_crtp : public observer_crtp<Derived, Events>...
{
public:
    using observer_crtp<Derived, Events>::Update...;
};

and then
class manager : public observers_crtp<manager, eventA, eventB>
{
public:
    template <typename Event>
    void UpdateT(const Event& ) { /* do something */ }
};


Here is a possible variation with CRTP. The idea is to propose a  Template Method design pattern through static polymorphism.
In particular, one can define a generic update method that can call a common method and also (if existing) a specific method for event classes that propose such a specific behavior.
Note that it uses if constexpr and requires clause in a "not so beautiful" way in order to check whether a specific method exists for a given event type. It is somehow a CRTP at two levels and I strongly suspect that there is a better/simpler way to achieve this.
#include <iostream>

struct eventA {};
struct eventB {};
struct eventC {};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template<typename DERIVED, typename EVENT>
struct observer
{
    auto update (EVENT const& event) 
    {
        // common behavior.
        common (event);
        
        // specific behaviour
        static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->specific (event);
    }

    auto common (EVENT const& event)
    {
        // we can do here common stuff
        std::cout << "common stuff here\n";
    }
};

template<typename DERIVED, typename...EVENTS>
struct observers : observer<observers<DERIVED,EVENTS...>,EVENTS>...
{
    using observer<observers,EVENTS>::update...;

    template<typename EVT>
    auto specific (EVT const& event) 
    {
        if constexpr (requires {static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->specific (event); } )
        {
            static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)->specific (event);
        }
    } 
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct manager : observers<manager, eventA,eventB,eventC>
{
    auto specific (eventA const& event) 
    {
        std::cout << "specific for eventA\n"; 
    } 
};

int main() 
{
    manager mgr;
    
    mgr.update (eventA{});
    mgr.update (eventB{});
    mgr.update (eventC{});
}

Demo

Update: modification of update -> no need for if constexpr there since the method exists in observers
Demo
